# How to pull all data from couch DB into R

Tags: r, couchdb

Need help to pull all data from couch DB.

Inside Couch DB I have one database named "resume"
    Inside that resume database number of id contain data.
    I need all id data inside a data frame.

Need help, any snipped code will be very helpful for me.

Comment: I have tried both , I can pull data id wise one by one. but i want to pull all data inside the database.

Comment: Ah, so this is a couch query issue, not an R issue. Hopefully a couch person can chime in on how to do a select * type query.

Comment: I think I could'n explain, my question is I want to pull data from couch DB to R. I need only R Script to pull all data from a couch DB (dm name resume). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is transform the output to CSV right in CouchDB. I did this in a project once (not R, but also a tool to do statistics) and it worked quite well. You can use list functions of CouchDB for that: it gives you an iterator over the view's output plus methods for writing to the HTTP response. The following link gives you a lot of information on this: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/couchapp/ddocs.html#list-functions
Hope this helps - let us know...